# NoMethodError for object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2

Here is the code

```
  #add email of team lead of the current user
  def add_the_tl_email(to_address, session_user_id)
    ul = UserLevel.find_by_user_id(session_user_id)
    if !ul.team.nil? && !ul.role.nil?
      User.user_status('active').joins(:user_levels).where(:user_levels => {:position => 'tl', 
                                                      :role => ul.role, 
                                                      :team => ul.team }).each do
        |u| to_address << u.email 
      end
    end
  end
```

The error from spec:

```
  1) CustomersController GET customer page 'create' successful should create one customer record
     Failure/Error: post 'create', :customer => @customer
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `team' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:36:in `add_the_tl_email'
     # ./app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:15:in `notify_tl_dh_ch_ceo'
     # ./app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:27:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:48:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

team is a field in user_level. Here is the user_level in factory:

```
Factory.define :user_level do |level|

  level.role                 "sales"
  level.position             "member"
  level.team                 1
  level.association          :user
end
```

In rails console, the ul.team.nil? returns either true or false on test data generated by factory.

Since team is a field in user_level, why there is error in spec like:          NoMethodError:
           undefined method `team' for nil:NilClass ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please write a title that makes sense and is relevant. The issues if that `nil.team` is not a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call in

```
 ul = UserLevel.find_by_user_id(session_user_id)
```

returned `nil` and thus `nil` was assigned to `ul`.

So when you called

```
!ul.team.nil?
```

Ruby tried to call `team` on `nil`.  `nil` is an instance of `NilClass` and there is no method named `team` on `NilClass`.

Answer (score 3):

The issues is that `nil.team` is not a method*

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `team' for nil:NilClass
```

That is, `ul` evaluates to `nil`: check `ul.nil?` before checking `ul.team.nil?`... but might want to find out why the find failing to start with ;-)

Happy coding.

---

*This is what the *real error message says*, the title of the post is garbage :-/